# Add object to the list using bounded type parameter

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to create generic class which will get type(T) and which will contain List and method for adding some objects inherited from this type(T).

```
public abstract class Vehicle<P> {
    List<? extends P> passengers = new ArrayList<>(); 
    public <T extends P> void addPassenger(T pass){
        passengers.add(pass);//error
    }
}
```

But I get an error on the marked row:

> The method add(capture#1-of ? extends P) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (P)

How can I do this things correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done like this

```
public class Vehicle<P> {

    List<P> passengers = new ArrayList<>();

    public <T extends P> void addPassenger(T pass) {
        passengers.add(pass);
    }
}
```

Add now we can add the passenger:

```
    A a = new A("a");  // A superclass
    B b = new B("b");  // B extends A
    C c = new C("c");  // C extends B
    D d = new D();     // not extending A

    Vehicle<A> vehicle = new Vehicle<>();
    vehicle.addPassenger(a);
    vehicle.addPassenger(b);
    vehicle.addPassenger(c);   // passenger of type A,B and C can be added
    vehicle.addPassenger(d);   // !ERROR: passenger of type D can't be added.
```

Comment: The `T` here is pointless. It's exactly the same as `public void addPassenger(P pass)`

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is add pass that is of type 'T' to a List that is of 'type that extends P'.
Hence, you have to update the type of List to be same as 'pass' or type of 'pass' to be same as type of List.

```
public abstract class Vehicle<T> {
  List<T> passengers = new ArrayList<>();
  public void addPassenger(T pass){
    passengers.add(pass);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer to add an explanation _why_ this solves OP's problem? Code-only answers tend to be less useful.